# How to select values based on another duplicate value - c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

What I need is When User try to add new Item there should be query whether This ItemCode is in the OrderProductLine or not. if yes, a message box has to Display"This product already in the List" else a message box has to display "You can add this Item". So i can call the method later.

**Example:**

[Form for User add product to OrderProductLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88433.jpg)

Above in the link you can see User already added to two Item to the list(OrderProductLine). So if User try to add same Item again the Message Box has to Display.

It come something like this...
FROM OrderProductLine WHERE OrderNo = "3" SELECT ALL ItemCode

**DataModel**

```
public class OrderProductLine
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int OrderNo { get; set; } // Foreign Key
        public int ItemCode { get; set; } // Foreign Key
        public int SupplierID { get; set; } // Foreign Key
        [Required]
        public float Quantity { get; set; }
        public float Discount { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public float Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

[All Record of OrderProductLines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pQSq.jpg)

**DataGridView**

```
private void LoadProductData()
        {
            try
            {
                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                using (ShopDbContext db = new ShopDbContext())
                {
                    var value = int.Parse(lblOrderNo.Text);
                    var prd = from OrderProductLine in db.OrderProductLines
                              where OrderProductLine.OrderNo == value
                              select new
                              {
                                  ID = OrderProductLine.ID,
                                  ItemCode = OrderProductLine.ItemCode,                                  
                                  Quantity = OrderProductLine.Quantity,
                                  Discount = OrderProductLine.Discount,
                                  Amount = OrderProductLine.Amount
                              };
                    bs.DataSource = prd.ToList();
                    ProductList.DataSource = bs;
                    ProductList.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

So far I have tried

```
ShopDbContext db = new ShopDbContext();

var ICode = int.Parse(txtItemCode.Text);
var lblOrd = int.Parse(lblOrderNo.Text);

var query = db.OrderProductLines.Where(p => p.OrderNo == lblOrd).Select(u => u.ItemCode == ICode).FirstOrDefault();

if (query != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This Item Already added");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You can add this Item");
}
```

It is not right one the 
Outcome: always true

Comment: Break apart your line `var query = ...` into several lines so you can follow it step by step.  By doing this you can find out what items are being returned by the `.Where` clause.

Comment: Try `if (db.OrderProductLines.Any(p => p.ItemCode == ICode && p.OrderNo == lblOrd))`.

Comment: If i got your case right, you should use **db.OrderProductLines.Where(p => p.OrderNo == lblOrd).FirstOrDefault(u => u.ItemCode == ICode);**. Because by select statement linq returns true or false responses and you select the first true or false among these responses, Then checking boelean whether it is null, doesn't make sense

Comment: @MikeH Thank you for your Idea.

Comment: Steve Greene, Furkan Öztürk Thank you for both of your help & Explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked According to Furkan Öztürk response.

```
var query = db.OrderProductLines
            .Where(p => p.OrderNo == lblOrd)
            .FirstOrDefault(u => u.ItemCode == ICode);

if (query != null)
{
     MessageBox.Show("This Item Already added");
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("You can add this Item");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also worked According to  Steve Greene response.

```
if (db.OrderProductLines.Any(p => p.ItemCode == ICode && p.OrderNo == lblOrd))
{
    MessageBox.Show("This Item Already added");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You can add this Item");
}
```